# How to access input:required:invalid using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I am validating forms using HTML5. So, if my input field is required, and invalid, I can change the CSS styles to reflect that using the following code:

```
input:required:invalid, input:focus:invalid {
    color: red;
}
```

Now, how can I determine if an input element is required:invalid or focus:invalid using jQuery?

Something like this:

```
 if ( $('#myInput') has the attribute invalid) { Do something }
```

Obviously, the condition in the if statement needs to be a condition. How can I figure this out? Thanks!

Comment: `if( $('#myInput').is(':invalid'))` ?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol sounds convenient but not a valid jQuery selector

Comment: @charlietfl Huh, that's kind of dumb, since it's a valid CSS selector and jQuery is supposed to wrap CSS... But `if( $('#myInput:invalid').length)` will work, since that passes it through `querySelectorAll`. If `.length` is non-zero, then the input was invalid.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol not the same thing though. jQuery has numerous pseudo classes that aren't css selectors (`:input`, `:animated` , `:lt()` etc) and uses it's own selector extension system for them. http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/jquery-selector-extensions/

Answer (score 2):

Could use native `checkValidity()` inside a filter. There is no jQuery selector for `invalid`

```js
var invalidInputs = $('#myForm :input').filter(function() {
  return !this.checkValidity();
}).each(function() {
  console.log(this.name, ' error message is ', this.validationMessage)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <input name="noValidation">
  <input name="required_w_value" value="test" required>
  <input name="required_no_value" required>
</form>
```